# (Geometry) Proof type questions

Tags: geometry

[image: question]
[image: answer]

Can someone please explain to me the given question and proof? otherwise I might just have to end up dropping my maths course because unfortunately I'm not understanding anything from my teacher. I'm not really 'seeing' the concept, if that makes sense.

Regards,

Comment: The line $DE$ splits the inner angle in half. You have to prove that it therefore splits the outer angle in half. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: couldnt u just label ABD and CBD as x, then since CBE and ABE are the only other angles on the straight line segment DE, they must both be 180-x. as angles on a straight line add to 180

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you might be tripped up on is the 180. The 180 comes from the 'line' DE, which is a straight angle, you know, a 180. And since 180 is a constant, subtracting either $\angle CBD$ or $\angle ABD$ you'll end up with the same number.

Comment: so in these type of questions, I have to be on the look out for constants?

Comment: Most definitely yes, because looking at it won't tell you for sure if they are equal (they might be off by a smidge unnoticed to the naked eye, technically). But if you have a value, you can treat it like a reference. There's a quote from one of my math books that says, "Geometry helps you understand the problem, algebra lets you solve the problem".